# GET parameter not showing as set

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL like this:

http://www.website.com/Bob/post/3/?test

Here's the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/post/([^/]*)/?$ /post.php?user=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

When I try to check if the `test` parameter is set, it returns false:

```
if (isset($_GET['test'])) {
    echo 'Set';
} else {
    echo 'Not Set';
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: you don't have a test parameter. you have a `user` and `id` parameter if your htaccess is correct. Try doing a `var_dump($_GET);` and see what is being produced. or the `test` parameter is NULL which `isset` will produce a false response.

Comment: You might need the [QSA](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA) flag, `[L,QSA]`

Comment: Yes `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/post/([^/]*)/?$ /post.php?user=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]` will fix this issue.